# I can't debug anymore in Eclipse...only Class.class opens

Tags: eclipse, class, debugging

When I try to debug my implementation of a SpringBoot application in Eclipse Oxygen the debugging does not start anymore. Instead of starting the debug seesion the `Class.class` file occurs in a file tab but nothing else happens.

When I run the app everything works well.

Yesterday I could debug without any problems.

What is the reason for this behaviour and how can I debug my implementation again???

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm...it's weird but: 
I had a bunch of breakpoints gathered over the time. I t helped to delete all breakpoint. 
(I could imagine that a breakpoint in Class.class was set somehow.)

Comment: The same happened to me too, and removing all breakpoints solved it.